# Why is $\int \big( \nabla{p_{1}} \cdot \nabla{p_{2}} \big) = \int s_{1}p_{2}$ when $-\nabla^{2} p_{1} = s_{1}$ and $-\nabla^{2} p_{2} =s_{2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, divergence-operator

This came up while reading something about the [porous medium equation,](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mccann/assignments/477/Otto01.pdf) (see equation 10 of the link if curious) I don't have much background in PDE's so I apologize for my ignorance.

> Suppose that $-\nabla^{2} p_{1} = s_{1}$ and $-\nabla^{2} p_{2} =s_{2} $ then does $\int \big( \nabla{p_{1}} \cdot \nabla{p_{2}} \big) = \int s_{1}p_{2}?$

Here the $s_{i}$ and $p_{i}$ are functions on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $\nabla^{2}$ is the Laplacian operator.

Comment: Is $\nabla^2$ the laplacian operator?

Comment: I think this might just require calculating $\nabla^2 (p_1 p_2)$ and integrating. You might have to apply some form of stokes' theorem as well.

Comment: Yes, it is the Laplacian operator

Comment: What is the integration domain?

Comment: I believe it should be $\mathbb{R}^{N}$

Comment: Consider the following expression: $\mbox{div }(p_2\nabla p_2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just integration by parts (sometimes called stokes theorem with multidimensional vectors). For functions vanishing at infinity
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \nabla p_1\cdot\nabla p_2 = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{div}(\nabla p_1)p_2 = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Delta p_1\,p_2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} s_1\,p_2,
$$
where $\Delta$ denotes the Laplacian.

If you are not familiar with multidimensional calculus, just write on a basis and integrate by parts for each coordinate
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \nabla p_1\cdot\nabla p_2 &= \sum_j \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \partial_j p_1\partial_j p_2
\\
&= -\sum_j \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \partial_j^2p_1\, p_2 = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Delta p_1\,p_2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} s_1\,p_2,
\end{align*}
$$